# Apache redirect to another folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my application I have my domain pointing to the index.php. I have a folder called "mod" and I want to redirect all the request from the "mod" folder to the index.php

Here is my rule in the sites-enabled conf file but it is not working, means I'm still able to access the files in the mod folder from url

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^mod/.* http://domain.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can someone tell me what is the issue here?

Comment: I'm still able to access the files in the mod folder. @anubhava I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?mod/ /index.php [L]
```

Note optional leading slash before `mod` which will make this rule work in .htaccess as well in Apache config files. Also I removed `R` to avoid external redirect.

Edit:

Seems there is problem with ajax requests. So we need to differentiate the ajax requests by sending ajax=1 for ajax requests and change the rule.

Create a .htaccess file in mod folder and add these lines

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)ajax= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L,R]
```

Comment: No effect at all. I tried it in both the places. I created the htaccess file in my mod folder and tried that. But it is not working

Comment: My .htaccess is enabled. If I put any random string in my .htaccess file it generates 500 (internal server) error

Comment: It is working. But the problem is it is not redirecting. Seems it is including the index.php, no css is applied. I think it should redirect. It should redirect to index.php? Isn't it?

Comment: Yes. It worked. So,  R is for redirecting. Isn't it?

Comment: But this ll work for ajax call? Actually mod folder is for ajax calls. It is not working for ajax calls. For ajax it should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117385/discussion-between-anubhava-and-ling-s).